# Xamarin.iOS async ViewDidLoad

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, async-await, azure-ad-msal

I am using the Microsoft Authentication Library and Azure AD B2C to provide a login for my mobile app. With that I can provide a button with an async event handler that will start the login process:

```
// iOS example
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    LoginButton.TouchUpInside += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            await app.AcquireTokenAsync(...);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

When first opening the app, I need to be able to silently log them in using `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`. I have seen lots of documentation saying that you should never use async on a void returning method unless it is an event handler, but in this case I need to do it on `ViewDidLoad()`. If I swallow any exceptions is this acceptable?

```
// is async void okay in this scenario? if not, where else can I put it?
public async override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();


    try
    {
        await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(...);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // swallow
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
try
{
    await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(...).ContinueWith(
                t =>
                {
                    if (t.Exception != null)
                    {
                        t.Exception.Handle(
                            ex =>
                            {
                                if (ex is TaskCanceledException)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Task cancelled {0}", ex);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                                }
                                return false;
                            });
                    }
                },
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    /Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

You can encapsulate it as an extension method so is easier to use.

Comment: should this ContinueWith be causing a TaskCanceledException? that is what I am seeing

Comment: It shouldn't. The continueWith is call after you Task has completed. The parameter received is the previous Task.

Comment: The success case causes a TaskCanceledException...at least the way the code is written now.